# loading swf actionscript 2.0 video in flex mobile project

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am creating a flex android app in flash builder 4.7. I am trying to load swf videos from the server url into the app. But when I try to test it in my phone, it shows a warning that the application is attempting to run actionscript 2.0 which is not supported on smart phone profile. What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: I don't use Flash Builder but just check the program or Export settings. Maybe they are AS2 by default and you must change them? Also makes sure your app loads a real video file (MP4 or FLV). It should **not** try to load another external SWF that has code to load a video...

Comment: This have explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985261/using-as2-in-air-application

Comment: PS: Use the **[NetStream API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play())** (see code example) to load your video file (MP4 or FLV). If you are loading SWF files, **that is not a real video** (SWF is either just multiple JPEGs of imported video frames or else it has AS2/AS3 code to load the actual FLV/MP4 file...). For security reasons, mobile does not run code from external loaded SWF files. Export animations as video or else use a video converter on the SWF files. Try this **[onine tool](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4)**

Comment: Just forget about using AS2 anymore for mobile packaging. AS2 is dead long ago and for mobile too, try not to use any code in external swf. Only use external swf for graphics assets. if you need to load video embeded in swf, make sure swf don't have any scripts on them or else only graphic assets will render while all scripts like players may be broken.